# Single Quadcore or Dual Dualcore?

Tags: cpu, multi-processor

If you have to choose (everything else being equal) between one processor with four cores, and two processors with dual core, what are the points in favour of each solution?

Comment: Please note. This question could be considered subjective. Please keep it civil. Also since it is asking for opinions, and there is *no single correct answer* I have switched this to wiki.

Comment: well, I do think there is a correct answer: the one that tells me the advantages and disadvantages of each solution clearly and extensively to make a proper choice. Anyway, no problem.

Comment: Anyway a Quad-Core CPU is actually a Dual Dual-Core in 1 single package.

Comment: Why not Dual Quadcore ;)

Comment: @Nick: if you hand in the money, why not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Physically speaking, the latency between two separate processors separated by centimeters is a knock on multi-CPU configurations in itself. However, these configurations typically have independent cache, which is different than single-die / dual-die multicore system. These shared-cache architectures gain considerable performance increases when the right application is running (e.g. one with few-to-no cache misses, using all the cores), but the cores are still vying for a shared resource which can cause the opposite to happen - terrible cache misses that kill performance.

Unfortunately every board and architecture is different. Your question can be answered or at least guessed at for a given application. As it stands, though, the jury is out when it comes to raw performance.

Cost, however, is another matter. I think it's obvious given the proliferation of multi-core systems that cost is in the quad-core's favour.

Answer (score 5):

One major benefit to a single quad core would be power and heat/cooling savings overall.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would like 1 quadcore, and my reasoning is so that 1 processor can manage the data and work directly with the ram instead of having 2 processors compete for data management. I am sure there are other explanations.

Comment: Fair comment, however keep in mind that dual processor motherboards are rigged differently from single core processors, therefore there isn't much competition between processors. The same rule applies scaling up.